# How do pipes work with purrr map() function and the "." (dot) symbol

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

When using both pipes and the map() function from purrr, I am confused about how data and variables are passed along. For instance, this code works as I expect:

```
library(tidyverse)

cars %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  map(~hist(.))
```

Yet, when I try something similar using ggplot, it behaves in a strange way.

```
cars %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  map(~ggplot(cars, aes(.)) + geom_histogram())
```

I'm guessing this is because the "." in this case is passing a vector to aes(), which is expecting a column name. Either way, I wish I could pass each numeric column to a ggplot function using pipes and map(). Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could also try `cars %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  map(~qplot(.))`, although ggplots' quick plot is considered deprecated I think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
cars %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  map2(., names(.), 
       ~{ggplot(data_frame(var = .x), aes(var)) + 
           geom_histogram() + 
           labs(x = .y)                    })

# Alternate version
cars %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  imap(.,
       ~{ggplot(data_frame(var = .x), aes(var)) + 
           geom_histogram() + 
           labs(x = .y)                    })
```

[image]

[image]

There's a few extra steps.

- Use `map2` instead of `map`. The first argument is the dataframe you're passing it, and the second argument is a vector of the `names` of that dataframe, so it knows what to `map` over. (Alternately, `imap(x, ...)` is a synonym for `map2(x, names(x), ...)`. It's an "index-map", hence "imap".).
- You then need to explicitly enframe your data, since `ggplot` only works on dataframes and coercible objects.
- This also gives you access to the `.y` pronoun to name the plots.

Comment: what is the meaning of the first dot in map2(., ..)?

Comment: The first dot is just for clarity. The pipe automatically puts the LHS as the first argument. Since I was using the `.` and `names(.)` as the first two args, I thought it was clearer to show the parallel construction.

Answer (score 9):

You aren't supposed to pass raw data to an aesthetic mapping. Instead you should dynamically build the data.frame. For example

```
cars %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  map(~ggplot(data_frame(x=.), aes(x)) + geom_histogram())
```

Comment: I was surprised that this approach worked, but since dataframes are really lists of vectors, I suppose it makes sense.

Comment: I like the concision of this. Is there a way to add an x-axis title without resorting to `map2`? Or does purrr treat each "." iteration as a numeric vector without a name? Thanks!!

Comment: Alas, purrr does not pass along names. You need to pass it explicitly as with map2